# What's the difference between "made from" and "made of"

Tags: meaning, differences, prepositions

What's the difference between "made from" and "made of"?
Could anyone give me some examples?

Comment: [Why is wine made from grapes but tables are made of wood?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/11237/why-is-wine-made-from-grapes-but-tables-are-made-of-wood/11248#11248) from our sister site, ELL.

Answer (score 10):

As a general rule, if an object consists of a material that has not been changed in any significant way then we say "*made of*":

> This table is made of wood.
>
> That table is made of glass.

If, on the other hand, the material is significantly changed in the process of making the object, then we generally say "*made from*":

> Paper is made from wood.
>
> Glass is made from melted sand.

You can also use "*made out of*", especially when referring to a surprising use of the original material:

> I have a Christmas tree made out of wire coat hangers.

Note, however, you will encounter many examples in actual usage that contravene the above principles.